# NetSuite Saved Search to Calculate time elapsed from system note changes

Tags: datetime, case, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I want to calculate the time from when one field is set in the system notes to when it is changed again in a Transaction saved search.

Here are the 2 case formulas I created to get the date and time of when this field was set to True and when it was changed to false.

case when {systemnotes.field} = 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'T' then {systemnotes.date} end

case when {systemnotes.field} = 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'F' then {systemnotes.date} end

I want to find the difference between the 2 {systemnotes.date}. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.field} LIKE 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'T' THEN {systemnotes.date} END) - MAX(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.field} LIKE 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'F' THEN {systemnotes.date} END)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to see this in dd:hh:mm format if possible. I set the summary type to minimum, the function to Round to Hundredths and I edited the formula to this: (MAX(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.field} LIKE 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'T' THEN {systemnotes.date} END) - MAX(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.field} LIKE 'Problem Order' AND {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'F' THEN {systemnotes.date} END))*24 This give me the Hours but not the days and minutes. Do you have a better way to see this in a time format?